# Please review edited answer and vote to undelete answer if you agree

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I answered a question which was accepted and then went to other questions which I thought might be considered a duplicate question on the same topic and pasted a link to my answer.

As a result my answer to the question I believed to be duplicate was removed by a moderator. I am not sure of the exact reason that my answers were deleted however I edited one of the answers and resubmitted it. Please take a look and vote to undelete it if you believe the edit merits the answer to be undeleted.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569017

Comment: Please note that you shouldn't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)

Answer (score 9):

You left this exact same “answer” on three questions:

> I provided a detailed explanation of numpy.r_ which can be found by
>   navigating to:
>
> [Understanding the syntax of numpy.r_() concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468158/understanding-the-syntax-of-numpy-r-concatenation#59568830)

That raised an automatic flag. This kind of answer would have been deleted anyway, as it’s a link-only answer and worthless by itself. Post it as a comment instead or vote to close the questions as duplicate of the question that contains the original answer. Don’t duplicate answers verbatim nor just link to other answers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However for one of the answers I completely changed it. 

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569017

The answer that I am requesting to be undeleted is no longer just a worthless link as you stated. It is a full fledged original answer.

Comment: Well now *that’s* (mostly) a duplicate of your original, isn’t it‽

Comment: Well I did not copy and paste my original answer. I sat down and wrote an entirely different one. The reason they may have similarities is that the questions are on the same topic. My point is to answer a similar question. Since I cannot comment yet I initially thought of pasting a link but this was deleted so I then resorted to writing an entire answer which addresses specifically the question but as the topics are related the answers will be related as well.

Comment: I see, fair enough. I’ve undeleted it now.